# FolderBrowserDialog with Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments returns an empty list

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the FolderBrowserDialog in some WPF Applications.
It was working good until the Windows 10 Anniversary Update.

My FolderBrowserDialog is used to navigate inside "My Documents". Since the update, the dialog is only displaying an empty tree with "Documents" at top.
It's still working on other computers with an older version of Windows.

I haven't found anything on this issue. Did you encounter it? Do you know any workarounds or alternatives?

My code

```
FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments;
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this defect too.  The MyPictures, MyVideos, and MyMusic enumerators also don't work.  The MyComputer enum does work.

I've found if you set the RootFolder to MyComputer and the SelectedPath to the MyDocuments path then it works:

```
using (FolderBrowserDialog fb = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    fb.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
    fb.SelectedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    fb.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
    fb.ShowDialog();
}
```

[image]

The top level folder isn't "Documents" as you wanted, but at least you can expand it.

I've heard some people suggest to run the exe in Compatibility Mode (properties/Compatibility), but that didn't work for me.